# Cloth Filter with Collisions

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

Today I tried out the Cloth Filter in Blender 2.9 while in sculpt mode. I was hoping the filter would collide with other objects as they would with the cloth settings under the physics tab, but so far no luck. I was hoping to drape some shorts over a character’s legs using the cloth filter to get a few natural looking wrinkles, and then keep on sculpting afterwards.

Basically, what I am trying to do is the same as what is posted in the video here: https://developer.blender.org/D8019

Is this collision capability just not released yet, or is this something I should be able to accomplish today?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that collisions while sculpting will arrive in 2.91..not 2.90: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Sculpt